# The way to clone object in java by value - not by reference

Tags: java, clone, pass-by-reference

I want to copy my Object of class implemented by me not as reference order by value.

My code sometimes behaves in strange way.

This is my class Element

```
public class Element {
    int x;
    int y;
    public Element(){

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Example code that I am using:

```
public void fourthTurnElement6(){
    MainLoopClass.helpTurn=false;
    Element element1=firstPoint;
    Element element2=secoundPoint;
    Element element3=thirdPoint;
    Element element4=fourthPoint;
    element1.setX(firstPoint.getX());
    element1.setY(firstPoint.getY()+1);
    element2.setX(firstPoint.getX()+1);
    element2.setY(firstPoint.getY());
    element3.setX(firstPoint.getX()+1);
    element3.setY(firstPoint.getY()-1);
    element4.setX(thirdPoint.getX()+1);
    element4.setY(thirdPoint.getY());


    if(HelperMethods.detectTurnColision(element1,element2,
        element3,element4)){
            return;
    }

    if(HelperMethods.detectTurnRightWallColision(element1,
        element2,element3,element4)){
            return;
    }
    firstPoint=element1;
    secoundPoint=element2;
    thirdPoint=element3;
    fourthPoint=element4;
```

Is it possible that sometimes it will work proper but sometimes not? It seems in my code that `detectTurnColision` works fine but the issue is `detectTurnRightWallColision`. The second function is very simple but I don't think the error occurs there.

EDIT:
Do you see any error here:

```
    Element element1=firstPoint.clone();
    Element element2=secoundPoint.clone();
    Element element3=thirdPoint.clone();
    Element element4=fourthPoint.clone();


    element1.setX(firstPoint.getX());
    element1.setY((firstPoint.getY()));
    element2.setX(firstPoint.getX());
    element2.setY(firstPoint.getY()+1);
    element3.setX(firstPoint.getX());
    element3.setY(firstPoint.getY()+2);
    element4.setX(firstPoint.getX()-1);
    element4.setY(firstPoint.getY()+2);
    if((MainActivity.ELEMENTS-1-firstPoint.getY()<2) )
        return;
    if(HelperMethods.detectTurnColision(element1,element2,
        element3,element4)){
            return;
    }  
    if(HelperMethods.detectTurnRightWallColision(element1,
        element2,element3,element4)){
            return;
    }
    firstPoint.setX(element1.getX());
    firstPoint.setY(element1.getY());
    secoundPoint.setX(element2.getX());
    secoundPoint.setY(element2.getY());
    thirdPoint.setX(element3.getX());
    thirdPoint.setY(element3.getY());
    fourthPoint.setX(element4.getX());
    fourthPoint.setY(element4.getY());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the 'copy' part you can create a copy constructor or method in Element Class.

**constructor** :

```
public Element(Element element){
    this.x = element.x
    this.y = element.y
}
// ToDo handle null argument if needed if(element==null)return; 
// values will be set to 0.
```

*example*:

```
Element element1 = new Element();
Element element2 = new Element(element1);
```

**method** :

```
public Element clone(){
    Element newCloneElement = new Element();
    newCloneElement.x = x;
    newCloneElement.y = y;
    return newCloneElement;
}
// The above method can implemented as static with an Element argument
// and the values will be copied from the argument.
```

*example*:

```
Element element1 = new Element();
Element element2 = element1.clone();
```

I can not provide answer to the second question because you do not explain what the method does.

Comment: Hi, I am changing the element2 inner values and try give data back to the element1 and there are trashes. Do you may know why?

Comment: To change the value of an element you use element.setX(2);
However if your code is like 
Element element1=firstPoint;
if you change firstPoint, element1 changes too and vice versa.
So, there is a case you handle the variables the wrong way and change values you don't want

Answer (score 0):

You would add a copy method to your class and some constructor.

```java
    public class Element {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Element(){

        }

        public Element(int x, int y) {

        }

        public Element copy() {
            return new Element(x, y);
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

```java
        Element element = new Element(0, 0);

        Element secondElement = element.copy();

        assert element != secondElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, element1 and firstPoint are the same object, is this what you want ?

Besides, when you set element2 and element3 to firstPoint, it has already been modified before. It is probably an unwanted side effect.

element1,2,3,4 have to be independant objects :

```
Element element1 = new Element()
Element element2 = new Element()
Element element3 = new Element()
Element element4 = new Element()
```

However, Jason's solution is better, because this is how Java is meant to be handled.

Comment: could you take a look why last four assigning elements outputs trashes?The lines below my if statements

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what mainActivity.ELEMENT is, so I can't comment on your condition (but I think the problem stems from here).